# Buddy Class MemberInfo not returning custom attributes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, buddy-class

EDIT: I was able to get what I needed via this code, which pulled the list of buddy classes associated to my type - t is the type of my non-buddy class.

```
MetadataTypeAttribute[] metaAttr = (MetadataTypeAttribute[])t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true);
```

Question is in the commenting in code as well -

I have a custom attribute that is being applied to a buddy class (I'm using EF-DB first). However, when I try to get the memberinfo, I don't see the custom attribute. How do I pull the value of this attribute, using an expression like below?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

// I have a custom attribute...
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ExportNameAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string DisplayName;

    public ExportNameAttribute(string displayName)
    {
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }
}

// And I have a class with a metadata buddy class (to simulate how I need to do this with EF-DB first)
[MetadataType(typeof(AttributeTestMetaData))]
public partial class AttributeTest
{
    public string myAttribute { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeTestMetaData
{
    [ExportName("test")]
    public string myAttribute { get; set; }
}

// However, when I pull the member info for this property via an expression, I don't get the attribute back.
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mInfo = GetMemberInfo((AttributeTest at) => at.myAttribute); 
        Console.WriteLine(mInfo.CustomAttributes.Count().ToString()); // Outputs 0
    }

    public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
    {
        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member != null)
            return member.Member;

        throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a member access", "expression");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

MetadataTypeAttribute[] metaAttr = (MetadataTypeAttribute[])t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true);